# RegEx to remove brackets and blank spaces

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I've the following code

```
String[] helloWorld = {"Hello", "World"};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(helloWorld));
```

which prints

```
[Hello, World]
```

I need to remove the blank spaces and [ ] . And get the following value.

```
Hello,World
```

I've this `helloWorld.replaceAll("\\s+","")` to remove blank spaces but how do I remove the brackets as well.

Comment: Why don't you just change the `println()` ?

Comment: [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to :

```
String[] helloWorld = {"Hello", "World"};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(helloWorld).replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\s]", ""));
```

Since `[` and `]` are special symbols in Regex, they have to be escaped.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for regex here, especially since you can easily make many mistakes like removing `[` `]` which are parts of your tokens, or if elements could contain more than one word like `[foo bar, baz]`.

Simplest way to solve this problem is to use [`String.join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) added in Java 8.

```
String[] helloWorld = {"Hello", "World"};
System.out.println(String.join(",", helloWorld));
```

---

If you don't have Java 8 you can write your own method like

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements){
    if (elements.length == 0) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(elements[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        sb.append(delimiter).append(elements[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

If you can't use Java 8 and you don't want to reinvent the wheel you can use external method like `StringUtils.join` from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ library

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(helloWorld, ","));
```

Comment: Thanks Pshemo but the project I work doesn't have Java 8, so regEx is the only solution there.

Comment: @kumareloaded I added some alternatives in my answer.